# I'm trying to declare a null on an array that at one point in the game no longer exists

Tags: c#, arrays, random, types, null

I'm trying to apply a null on an array. The arrays are points where game prefabs are being instantiated. At some point in the game, these spawn points may be destroyed. When this happens, the code is still trying to access that spawn point even though it no longer exists, so I'm trying to make it null. So far I have been unsuccessful. This is the last thing in the game I need to fix. Help is appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public class podControl : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform [] spawns;
    public float spawnTime = 6f;
    public float secondSpawnTime = 3f;      
    public GameObject podPrefab;

    void Start ()
    {
        InvokeRepeating ("landingPod", spawnTime, secondSpawnTime);
    }

    void landingPod ()
    {
        int spawnIndex = Random.Range (0, spawns.Length);

        if (spawns != null) {
            Instantiate (podPrefab, spawns [spawnIndex].position, spawns [spawnIndex].rotation); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is this code supposed to be showing us?

Comment: Could you be more specific at what the issue is? What do you mean by being unsuccessful to set it to null? Does it throw exception somewhere? For example, if you are setting some item of the `spawns` array to null and then try to access it with `spawns[spawnIndex].position`, you will get object reference exception. Is that what is happening?

Comment: yes. sorry i forgot to mention what the error message was. it's fixed now that was the problem so thank you

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be

```
if(spawns[spawnIndex] != null)
```

Otherwise it's checking to see if the array is not null rather than the entry

Comment: right that's what i was thinking, but i didn't know how to declare one array null without doing it to the whole thing. The error msg is gone now thanks to you. Thanks!